# Activity not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-activity

Java code:

```
package com.piyush.bankai;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeParse extends Activity {
static final String BLOG_URL = "http://www.google.com/";
Document doc=null;
String linkText=null;
String linkHref=null;
//TextView a;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set layout view
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homeparse);

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Elements divs =  doc.select("#mp-itn b a");

    for (Element div : divs) {
           linkHref = div.attr("href");
           linkText = div.text();
        }


    try {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText(linkHref);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText("kalal");
    }


    for (Element div : divs)
        System.out.println(div.text());
    }
}
```

xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.piyush.bankai"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Flip"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Queries"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERIES" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Test"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".HomeParse"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HOMEPARSE" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"         />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

After running this project, all I can see in the console is installation success! and Done.That's it, the output is not being displayed in the android device. Please help me debug this bug.I have tried creating other projects and they seem to run fine.

Answer (score 2):

your manifest is wrong:

if you want home parse to be the launcher activity you have to put that intent filter on it.

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and remove from the .flip activity.

also this `<action android:name="android.intent.action.HOMEPARSE" />` is not a real thing and android do nothing with this line